# How to search the largest string in an array of strings

Tags: java

I need to find the largest string from an array of strings and also want to make sure that the string which comes out should include only those chars which are defined in a separate string.

For eg: if an array of strings contains `{"ABCAD","ABC","ABCFHG","AB"}`
and another string S have chars `"ABCD"`.

Then the largest string return here should be `ABCAD` as it contains only the characters defined in `S`.

```
public String findstring(String a, String[] arr)
{
    String s="";
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        //int m=0;

        if(arr[i].length() > s.length())
        {
            s = arr[i];

        }
    }

            for(j=0; j<s.length(); j++)                                                      
            {
                int m=0;
                for(k=0; k<a.length(); k++)
                {
                    if(m>0)
                    {
                        break;  
                    }
                    if((s.charAt(j)==a.charAt(k)))
                    {
                        m++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if(m==0)
                {
                    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
                    list.remove(s);
                    arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
                    findstring("ABCD", arr);
                }

            }
        return s;
}
}
```

I am not receiving any error and getting the largest string as `ABCFABCD` whereas `F` needs to be excluded and largest string should be `ABCAA`.
Its skipping all the checks, don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

You make recursive call but just ignore the returned value.

Try add return on recursive findstring.

```
   arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
   return findstring("ABCD", arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in better way using Regex:

```
public String findstring(final String a, final String[] arr) {
    String s = "";
    // Created pattern of the characters available in the String
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[" + a + "]*$");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      if (p.matcher(arr[i]).matches()) {

        if ("".equals(s)) {
          s = arr[i];
        } else if (arr[i].length() > s.length()) {
          s = arr[i];
        }
      }

    }

    return s;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the luxury of New & Much Better Java Powers with some elegant, readable and less lines of code... you can have a look at below snippet:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final String allowedChars = "ABCD";
    final char[] chars = allowedChars.toCharArray();
    String result  = Stream.of("ABCAD","ABC","ABCFHG","AB")
            .filter(s ->{
                for(char c: chars){
                    if(!s.contains(c+""))
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            })
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
            .orElse("No Such Value Found");
    System.out.println("Longes Valid String : " + result);
}
```

**Explanation:**

The code makes a `Stream` of `String` from `arrays` and `filter` only valid strings (*Strings which are not containing the allowed characters will simply be removed from the further processing*) and remaining `Stream` will be compared for the length *(using `Comparator`)*, and finally, longest valid `String` will be returned.

There may be a case where all the strings in array/Stream would be invalid, in such case, the code will return the Message "No Such Value Found" as String, however you can throw an exception, or you can return some own value for your custom logic, or you can return null, etc.

I've intentionally kept the String message and gave you the hint about learning other methods present in Java Stream so that you can explore more.

Keep Coding... and feel the Power of New JAVA. :)